# how to reformat GPT partition style to NFTS to install windows 10 pro

Tags: networking, windows-10

I want to install Windows 10 pro on a brand new machine INSPIRON 15-3552 that is currently running UBUNTU. I have formatted and deleted the partitions that appeared and created new ones to install windows 10 pro but The error message says Windows cannot be installed on GPT partition style. Windows must be installed on an NTFS formatted partition.
Please can anyone help me achieve the desired NTFS file format?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57522/discussion-on-question-by-john-msimi-how-to-reformat-gpt-partition-style-to-nfts).

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you two different **unrelated** things, but apparently, you've taken them to be related.

Your problem for now is that Windows cannot be installed on a GPT-style partition. (Forget about NTFS right now.) You must either boot the Windows Setup in UEFI mode (recommended), or use `diskpart` to erase your hard disk clean and then convert it to a MBR-style disk (not recommended).

Consult your motherboard's manual to find out how to boot Windows Setup in UEFI mode. Most of the time, it involves pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> during boot and selecting the boot device entry for Windows Setup that has "UEFI:" or "EFI:" prefix.

And please, get a couple of good computer books and read them. Trust me, doing so will improve your quality of life.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this breathtakingly advice and instructions on how to go about on EUFI I'll try to figure it out and I case I have any clarification I'll come back running for your help

Comment: When am I going to strike F8 or DELETE  button because I have tried at start up when Dell logo appeared but no observable changes.. Currently I don't have a manual because the laptop is a replacement of the faulty one. Kindly give me simple steps to follow so That I can arrive at installing windows thank you

Comment: Look up the make and model on the Internet and find its manual. They are usually free to download.